# FluentNHibernate; How to use QueryOver to put filter on sub-level object?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I'm trying to understand how to retrieve an object graph, where I want to put a filter on a sub-level object. So considering below classes. I want the query to retrieve the full collection of A, with their full collections of B, but for the collections of C, I want only to retrieve element of a certain range of dates, based on the "time" property.

I'm trying to understand this material: 
http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx#Associations

Maybe it should be obvious, but I have a hard time seeing how to use the extensions for this 3rd level restriction. So would really appreciate some help..

```
 Class A
   public List<B> Bs;

 Class B
   public List<C> Cs;

 Class C
   public DateTime time;
```

My attempt so far:  But it gives exception;

```
IQueryOver<A, B> q = session.QueryOver<A>()
    .JoinQueryOver<B>(a => a.Bs).JoinQueryOver<C>(b => b.Cs)
    .Where(e => e.time.Date == System.DateTime.UtcNow.Date);
```

> Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`2[A,C]'
>   to type 'NHibernate.IQueryOver`2[A,B]'.

Comment: "var" solves this problem. From the exception msg i'd say u just change IQueryOver<A, B> to IQueryOver<A, C>. The second generic will probably always be what u last JoinQueryOver. The alternative is to use the alias'd joins (my preference).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to cast the results to a list at some point, I would use:

```
session.QueryOver<A>()
.JoinQueryOver<B>(a => a.Bs)
.Fetch(a => a.Bs).Eager
.JoinQueryOver<C>(b => b.Cs)
.Where(e => e.time.Date == System.DateTime.UtcNow.Date).List<A>
```

The key bit is that the JoinQueryOver is only for building the where clause.
To include collections via eager loading, you need to use Fetch.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe my attempt was misleading; This returns one List<A> element for each instance of C that meets the "where" condition (Duplicates of A). But what I'm looking for is to get a domain object that represents exactly the database, except only including the C elements that meets the criteria.  So if database has 1 row in Table A, 1 row in Table B, and 10 rows in Table C, query should return a list with a single element A, with a single sub-element B, with X elements C, depending on how many meets the where condition.

Answer (score 0):

if the above answer gives you duplicates it is because its an classic select n+1 problem. See http://ayende.com/blog/4367/eagerly-loading-entity-associations-efficiently-with-nhibernate

for a way to efficiently load those collection without the duplication problem.